# Como remover registros mysql de meia hora (ou mais) atrás

Tags: php, mysql, sql, script

Preciso remover registros mysql que tenham feitos sido feitos meia hora (ou mais) atrás. Ou seja, deixar somente os registros dos últimos 30 minutos. Isso toda vez que um certo script php rodar. Como faço?

Comment: você tem um campo com a hora no registro? se tiver é só fazer a comparação com a hora atual.

Comment: Essas funções de data do MYSQL vão lhe ajudar: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
DELETE FROM nometabela 
WHERE campodatahorainsercao < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Perceba o seguinte:

**Tudo** que tiver na tabela que foi inserido a mais de 30 minutos será deletado.

Serão deletados todos os registros com data inferior a data do momento da execução - 30 minutos. Ou seja, só permanecerão os mais recentes que não completaram 30 minutos ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, como não tem muitos detalhes vou imaginar que você tenha uma tabela de usuários, nessa tabela tem inserts constantes o dia todo.

Ai no usuario você teria, login, senha, registradoEm, UltimaAlteraco

Bastaria você fazer um delete com base na data registradoEm, passando como parâmetro um objeto Data de meia hora antes

supondo que são 20/01/2017 20:00:00 em ponto

Você roda o script feito em PHP

aí basta fazer

delete from usuario where registradoEm > 20/01/2017 19:30:00

Com base na hora atual que é 20/01/2017 20:00:00 em ponto
eu mandei como parâmetro meia hora antes que são 20/01/2017 19:30:00

Deleta para min todos registros "registradoEm" acima da 20/01/2017 19:30:00

Todos todos usuários "registradoEm" que forem maior que 20/01/2017 19:30:00 serão apagados. Em outras palavras tudo oque foi registrado no período de 30 minutos sera apagado.